# PHP Form Validation (Required Fields)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

**Please read Edit 2 Below**

I am dynamically generating a form for a quiz. The questions and answers are taken from a MySQL database. The types of controls on the form are Checkboxes, Radio Buttons and Textboxes.

My validation needs to :
1) Check that a radio button is selected for all the relevant questions (By default none are selected).
2) Check that at least one Checkbox is selected for all the relevant questions.
3) Check that ANYTHING is entered in the Textboxes.

I found several examples on how to do this, but since I am generating the form dynamically, I ran into a problem.

Algorithm I am using for form generation is :

```
Loop to get Questions from Database
{
  Store "Type" of Question in variable X (Type = Single Choice 'c' (Radio button), Multi Choice 'm' (Checkbox), User Entry 'u' (Textbox)

  Loop to get Answers for current Question
   {
     Switch(X)
     {
       case 'c'
         Load each answer into separate radio buttons, Name = Question number.
       break
       case 'm'
         Load each answer into separate checkboxes, Name = Question number.
       break
       case 'u'
         Place textbox, Name = Question number.
       break
      }
    }
}
```

The data is then submitted and stored in MySQL.

I am tried to load all the form elements from POST into an array, and check if they have a value, however I then realized that this would check if each individual element had a value, which is not what I am looking for.

What would be the best approach for this? Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Edit 2:

I managed to solve this problem for radio buttons and text boxes using jQuery.validate. I used the source code of [this](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html) page as an example. However, it does not work for checkboxes! (I even copied the source code they used for their checkboxes directly into my page, it still does not work. Only the first checkbox is highlighted, and clicking the others does not remove the validation.

This is the segment of code that I copied from his website.

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Spam</legend>
            <label for="spam_email">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_email" value="email" name="spam[]" required minlength="2">
                Spam via E-Mail
            </label>
            <label for="spam_phone">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_phone" value="phone" name="spam[]">
                Spam via Phone
            </label>
            <label for="spam_mail">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_mail" value="mail" name="spam[]">
                Spam via Mail
            </label>
            <label for="spam[]" class="error">Please select at least two types of spam.</label>
        </fieldset>
```

Am I missing something here? Is there something else that I should have also copied over? (I have both the included files included in my page as well)

Comment: Take a look at [HTML5 validation](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation). Certainly a better option then displaying error message via alert.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you! But like I said, I am looking for guidance as to how to make it so that among a group of 4 option buttons, any one is selected, etc. I will try to implement this in my outer loop and see what I can do with this!

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery, try this (workes for both radios and checkboxes):

```
var isSpamValid = $('input[name=spam\\[\\]]:checked').length > 0;
```